# Calling Stored Procedure with Parameter and Multiple Result Set Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a stored procedure `uspGetProductAndCategory` which is accepting a parameter `@SupplierID` and returns the products, categories and suppliers [these tables from the `NorthWindDatabase`].

My problem is when I am integrating this stored procedure with an `.edmx` it's generating one method in my `ContextEntityClass` as `uspGetProductAndCategory` with a return type of `ObjectResult<uspGetProductAndCategory_Result>`. But this complex type is about only 1st result set.

I have read many topics on "How to Call Multiple Result Set SP in EF 6" but didn't get any solution yet. After changing the function import and other elements through XML editor as describe [here](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/30738a7c-5176-4333-aa83-98eab8548da5.aspx), how I will call the function `uspGetProductAndCategory_Result` which is already returning `ObjectResult<uspGetProductAndCategory_Result>`

Here's all the screen shot

After importing the stored procedure into the `ContextEntityClass`:

[image: ContextEntityClass]

`DbContext.edmx` after changing the function import

[image]

Comment: EF doesn't support multiple result sets from a stored procedure. Either change your procedure to return a single result set, or if you cannot do this, then you must use straight, raw ADO.NET to handle this stored procedure and its returned data

Answer (score 0):

A little bit advice. Do not use multiply result set in EF. That's it. May be I am so rude. But I spent a lot of time for it. And use simply another approach for SP calling. Not EF. I don't want to ad these approaches you can easily find them in internet.

EF goes on the way as 'code first' approach and SPs are not fit to this conception.